# Script only works while alert box is in the script

Tags: javascript, ajax

If I take the alert call out of the following script firebug says that results is undefined?`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Inventory Management</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="header">   
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var xhr;
                var results=getPlants(xhr,results);
                var plants=[];

                function getPlants(xhr,results){
                    try {
                        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();   
                    }catch(microsoft){
                        try{
                            xhr=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");                
                        }catch(othermicrosoft){
                            try{
                                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");               
                            }catch(failed){
                                xhr=false;
                                alert("ajax not supported");
                            }
                        }               
                    }

                    xhr.onreadystatechange= function () {
                        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
                            results = xhr.responseText;                     
                        }
                    }

                    xhr.open("GET","db_interactions.php",true);     
                    xhr.send(null);
                    alert("sent");
                    return results;
                }

                plants.inv=[];
                plants.split = results.split("~");

                for (var x=0;x<=plants.split.length-2;x++){
                    plants.inv[x]=plants.split[x].evalJSON();
                }

                document.write(plants.inv[1].scientific_name);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to reformat, for easier reading by SO users.

Comment: A few observations: don't use exceptions for flow control - they're very slow and makes code hard to read. Also, don't declare js functions in the middle of your markup; put them in the head or after the body. And reformat your code so we can read it, please.

Comment: And you may want to use one of the frameworks to take care of the browser-specific AJAX stuff. I thinkg you could reduce your script's volume by 50% by using JQuery or Prototype. (It's entirely optional and not really necessary. It just makes life easier.)

Comment: This has been asked before.  It's a common problem.  Search before you ask, please.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267454/javascript-and-ajax-only-works-when-using-alert

Answer (score 8):

The reason it's not working is because the `XmlHttpRequest` is *asynchronous*. What this means is that you **cannot** do `return results;`

Here's a timeline, with your alert box:

1. Create XmlHttpRequest
2. Send it
3. Alert box pops up and sits there for a while
4. XmlHttpRequest result comes back and sets the `results` variable in your `onreadystatechange` function
5. You click OK on the alert box
6. the function returns (the `return results` line)
7. Other code runs and does things with the `results` variable.

Here's the timeline without the alert box:

1. Create XmlHttpRequest
2. Send it
3. the function returns (the `return results` line)
4. Other code runs and does things with the `results` variable. This fails because it hasn't been set yet
5. XmlHttpRequest result comes back and sets the `results` variable in your `onreadystatechange` function

Instead you have to put the plants code (splitting, etc) in the `onreadystatechange` callback, or put it in it's own function, and call that function from the `onreadystatechange`

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the `plants` variable in the callback function assigned to the onreadystatechange property.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        results = xhr.responseText;
        // Populate the "plants" variable here, then call a function
        // that does something with the plants variable.
    }
}
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
xhr.open("GET","db_interactions.php",true);
```

you are telling the XMLHttpRequest to operate *asynchronously*. You are telling it to go off and do its work, calling the callback function at some unspecified time in the future, when the request has been fully processed. Change that `true` to `false`, and it will work as you expect. On the other hand, that function might hang indefinitely in the event of a network slowdown, etc., so *caveat programmor*.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function that sets the 'results' variable is asynchronous -- meaning that it will likely get set *after* the return statement, unless there's something to delay the return statement (e.g. an alert() call).

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest.send() is asynchronous. Without the alert the function runs faster than the ajax call and results is never initialized. You can fix this by changing the `true` in your open call to `false` to make it synchronous or set your global variable in your inline function