# AJAX does not synchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I've got an issue similar to this question here:
[Javascript and AJAX, only works when using alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267454/javascript-and-ajax-only-works-when-using-alert)

I have an AJAX call to update a field in the database when finalizing a form. However, the call doesn't seem to be reaching the controller. When I put an alert in, it works. I've currently got it set to synchronous because of the issue, but even then, without the alert, it only reaches the controller about 1 in every 5 or six times. This is the AJAX bit:

```
function finalize() {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure?"))
        return;

    $("#finalizebutton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/Operation/Finalize/";
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();

    $("#otherformstuff").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //a few disable calls
}
```

On the control side I have approximately:

```
public ActionResult Finalize()
{
    db.setfinalized(true);   //breakpoint here that only gets hit about 1 in 5 tests
    return Content("Finalized");
}
```

Even when there is an alert shoved in there it sometimes doesn't work.
Oddly enough, I put an alert for request.responseText and it gave me the response from the control without the control ever actually processing it...
Any thoughts on this are appreciated.

Comment: why aren't you using jQuery's AJAX?

Comment: @Daniel Why do you feel the need to use jQuery for everything?

Comment: bc he already has jquery included.

Comment: @Daniel Haha. I completely missed that. My bad.

Comment: @tylermwashburn: it may be overkill, but jquery does make life MUCH easier due to it hiding all kinds of stupid cross-browser issues you'd otherwise have to deal with yourself (and probably screw it up too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tell it to be synchronous.

Your problem is with this line:

```
request.open("GET", url, false);
```

The open method takes 3 arguments. Method, url, and the third is a boolean that tells it whether or not the request should be asynchronous.

Just change the false to true, and the request will be async.

```
request.open("GET", url, true);
```

But you could also just replace that entire block of XHR code with this one line..

```
$.get('/Operation/Finalize/');
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Could've sworn I tried that and got the same result.
Conceptually, though, I'm not sure I'm seeing why this isn't the other way around. If it's asynchronous, the javascript would continue executing while the call goes, thus completing the function. When it is synchronous, though, shouldn't it wait for the response before continuing? And in some cases, I received the correct response without the controller executing the appropriate code.

Comment: When it's asynchronous, it fetches the data while running the following code. When it's synchronous, after the send method is called, it waits for the response before executing anymore code.

Comment: That's what I thought it was supposed to do, but it didn't seem to be doing that. Even with asynch=false it disabled all elements indicated in the disabling lines after the send.

Comment: Because it finished loading whatever needed loading.