# jquery delegate or live function does not working properly

Tags: jquery

when i try to implement a delegate function in jquery, it works perfectly when i use a alert(), inside but it doesnt get triggered when i remove that alert.

```
$(document).delegate( "#j_id2030916047_790d592c", "click", function(){ 

  alert("");
  $("#p4").hide();
  $("#p5").hide();
  $("#p3").hide();

  $("#check2").change(function(){

    if($("#check2").is(":checked")) {

      $("#p2").hide();
    }
    else{

     $("#p2").show();
  }
});

$("input[name='sor']").change(function(){

  if($("input[name='sor']:checked").val()=="collegeStudent"){

    $("#p3").show();
    $("#p4").hide();
    $("#p5").hide();
  }
  else if($("input[name='sor']:checked").val()=="schoolStudent"){

    $("#p4").show();
    $("#p5").hide();
    $("#p3").hide();
  }
  else if($("input[name='sor']:checked").val()=="employee"){

    $("#p5").show();
    $("#p3").hide();
    $("#p4").hide();
  } 
  else{

    $("#p5").hide();
    $("#p3").hide();
    $("#p4").hide();
  }
});
```

u can see a alert in line 2, all the functionalities works well if the alert is present.. when i remove the alert, nothing works..

Comment: On two side notes: 1. are you sure you don't have any better node to delegate to than "document"? Surely there's a wrapper div that'll make things at least a little more efficient? 2. Although `.delegate()` isn't officially deprecated, I would recommend switching to `.on()` which will be feature-identical. It's just the event and selector that are reversed in terms of syntax.

Comment: i am using primefaces, it has an inbuilt jquery, it doesnt support on() function. instead of using delegate, i have used live function too.. but having the same problem..

Comment: I don't know primefaces (or JSF in general) but it seems to me that some of the problems stem from there. Surely you can upgrade the jQuery that primefaces uses?

Comment: ya i can, but actually the problem is not because of primefaces, i think.. its due to ajax... take a look at this similar problem.. [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267454/javascript-and-ajax-only-works-when-using-alert) clear solution is been provided ther, but still i cant able to follow it, as because primefaces have inbuilt ajax functionality, no way to change it rather..

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting this code within the document.ready event?

```
$(function () {  ....  });
```

It could be that your alert makes the difference because by that time, the document has loaded.

Comment: I too suspect it's a timing issue. Karthikeyan, wrap this all up in the document ready event and you should be good.

Comment: ya i am using this same code in document ready too.. to make it work during page load. but here in primefaces,  `<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="regPanel" styleClass="but"
     action="#{receiveclass.login}" ajax="false" ></p:commandButton>`   u can see an attribute called ajax=false, if it is given means, then document.ready itself working perfectly i dint need delegate or live functions. but when i keep ajax=true to validate my fields witout page load, i need live function to keep the functionalities working even after the command button(#j_id2030916047_790d592c) is clicked.

Comment: Try upgrading your version of jquery and then try using .on().

Answer (score 0):

Put your function into $(document).ready, and it will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).delegate( "#j_id2030916047_790d592c", "click", function(){ 

    //alert("");
        $("#p4").hide();
     $("#p5").hide();
     $("#p3").hide();
. . . 

   });
});
```