# how to resolve ajax post jquery in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

when i add alert(file) line after ajax block code work but when i remove alert(file) code not work .

this is work fine :

```
 function Delete(file) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Image.aspx/Delete",
            data: '{file: "' + file + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "jsondata",
            async: "true",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#statusBox").text("ok"); //alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $("#statusBox").text("error"+response.text);
               // alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            },
            complete: function () {
              //  $("#statusBox").text("completed");
            }


        });

        alert(file);

    }
```

if i remove alert(file) line code web method not work.

this my c# asp.net code web method :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Delete(string file)
{
    try
    {

        // int lastSlash=file.ind
        // Lesson learnt - always check for a valid URI
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(file, UriKind.Absolute))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(file);
            file = (uri.LocalPath);
        }
        //file=  file.Remove(0)

        //File.Delete(file);
         File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\" + file.Replace("/", @"\")));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }

    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: I can't see how adding `alert(file)` will affect the code that precedes it, but please define "doesn't work", what happens instead?

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console? press F12 and select the console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending the request asynchronously,try to make false asynchronous.
for more information take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267454/javascript-and-ajax-only-works-when-using-alert)

Comment: little problem when filename have space i have a problem to delete .

Comment: str = str.replace(/\s/g,''); use this to remove spaces from filename

Comment: when use str = str.replace(/\s/g,''); ? in my web method

Comment: nope u can use it on your  javascript before make a ajax request

Comment: data: '{file: "' + file.replace(/\s/g,'')+ '" }',

Answer (score 0):

I see three *(3)* errors in your code:

```
        data: '{file: "' + file + '" }',
        datatype: "jsondata",
        async: "true",
```

1. You are not sending a js object to the server.
2. `jsondata` is not a valid datatype.
3. `async` is a boolean and you are instead assigning a string value.

---

So the solution from here is:

```
        data: {file: file }, // send a object
        datatype: "text",    // change to text because you are returning "ok" string
        async: true,         // remove the quotes
```

---

Another suggestion is try with default headers:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Try removing this line and see.

Comment: i have it code to another page login.aspx but work fine.

Comment: not seen your backend code you are returning a string not the `json` so you can change to `text` instead.

Comment: my question is this. why  if i remove alert(file) line my code not work but after add just this line work fine .